# How can I print all matches by regex in files?

Tags: regex, bash, file, search

I have a directory `/usr/local/` and I need to find all files in that directory containing the strings which matches the following regex `.*\s-\scopy\s.*`. Is it possible to print all such mathces along with a full path file name their contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU `grep`, you may let `grep` do all the work for you:

```
grep -R '.*\s-\scopy\s.*' /usr/local
```

The `-R` switch tells `grep` to recurse into each directory. By default, `grep` will prepend the file name to each output.

You might want to use the `-I` flag too to ignore binary files.

By the way, the `.*` in this case is highly useless, you might as well just do:

```
grep -R '\s-\scopy\s' /usr/local
```

If your `grep` doesn't support the `-R` switch, a fully POSIX compliant solution is:

```
find /usr/local -type f -exec grep '[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]copy[[:space:]]' {} +
```

Comment: @St.Antario did you want the file names where the content of the file satisfies some condition?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for. I saud that I need to find all files containing the string matches the following regex....

Comment: I guess `\s` isn't POSIX, is it?  Try `[[:space:]]` for a properly POSIX regex.